# I get an error and a traceback trying to send a whatsapp with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I im tring to send a whatsapp with selenium and chromedriver, but when i run the code I get an error and a traceback.

I have tried everything that I could (I know a little of python, i'm lerning, and i know like nothing about selenium, but i have to get this working as soon as posible), I also have goggle a lot of this and tried a lot of things but i could not make this work.

If someone can help me I would be very grateful.

The error is this:

> [WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ====== [WDM] - Current google-chrome
> version is 89.0.4389 [WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 89.0.4389
> [WDM] - Driver
> [C:\Users\Crist.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\89.0.4389.23\chromedriver.exe]
> found in cache
>
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:56076/devtools/browser/0c5e0486-3e61-47d1-80f0-7ecfe21ffb6e
> Scan QR Code, And then Enter
>
> Logged In
> [14880:8104:0320/205615.019:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [20:56:15.018] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1056 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al
> sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
> [14880:8104:0320/205615.046:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [20:56:15.046] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting
> Default Adapter failed. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Crist\Desktop\Whattsapp mama\prueba.py", line 19, in
>
> input_box_search = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath_search))   File
> "C:\Users\Crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
>
> C:\Users\Crist\Desktop\Whattsapp
> mama>[14880:8104:0320/210116.161:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [21:01:16.161] USB: usb_service_win.cc:258 Failed to get device driver name: No se ha encontrado el elemento. (0x490)

And the code is this (it´s just what it takes to make it work):

```
contact = ["cristobal de toro", "cristobal", "gonzalo molina"]
text = "Hey, this message was sent using Selenium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
print("Scan QR Code, And then Enter")
input()
print("Logged In")
inp_xpath_search = "//input[@title='Search or start new chat']"
input_box_search = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath_search))
input_box_search.click()
time.sleep(2)
input_box_search.send_keys(contact)
time.sleep(2)
selected_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='"+contact+"']")
selected_contact.click()
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text"][@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath)
time.sleep(2)
input_box.send_keys(text + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is an `<input>` tag that has a `title` attribute that reads "Search or start new chat"?  Remember that everything must match exactly.

Comment: @TimRoberts nop, some code is not mine, but I ut it there because I have to make it work as soon as posible and i dont know so much about python or coding, do you know what I can do to make it work?

Comment: The pain of web scraping is that web sites change all the time.  It's not easy.  Do you actually get logged in when you scanned the QR code?  To debug this, you would have to look at the HTML source code of that logged in page to find the search box, and make sure the xpath you have will find it.  If you don't know how to do that, then this is not a project for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know that this is not a project for me, but i have to do it, but i what do you mean and how to do it, thanks.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did it work, but now i'm getting another error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Crist\Desktop\Whattsapp mama\prueba2.py", line 24, in <module>
    selected_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span['Buscar o empezar un chat nuevo'"+contact+"]")
  File "C:\Users\Crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span['Buscar o empezar un chat nuevo'cristobal de toro] because of the following error:

Comment: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span['Buscar o empezar un chat nuevo'cristobal de toro]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Comment: That didn't come from this code.  Perhaps you should post another question.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked at the code for the whatsapp web version, and it seems like each persons contact is assigned to a random uid each time you refresh the page (at least in my case). This means that you would need to use something like pyautogui to click on a predictable spot on the page. As for the actual input area, it's not even an input, so selenium wouldn't work in this case. I just wrote some example code to show how this would work - I'm on a 13" Laptop, so you may need to fix the coordinates with

```
pyautogui.position()
```

Install pyautogui with:

```
python3 -m pip install pyautogui
```

Heres the example code:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time

FIRSTX = 155
FIRSTY = 268

INPUTX = 605
INPUTY = 696






os.system('open https://web.whatsapp.com/')
time.sleep(7)

#Click on the first person in your contacts
pyautogui.click(x=FIRSTX, y=FIRSTY)
time.sleep(1)


#Click the input
pyautogui.click(x=INPUTX, y=INPUTY)
pyautogui.write("Your Message")
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: Yea, i thought on that, but I'm doing this because I have to do something to send whatsapps to more of 400 people, so if i would like to use pyautogui to this i should write like 400 positions, do you know another way I can do it?

Comment: You could just use a while loop / for loop, like
for i in range(401): 
 Scroll()
 Click()

And just use the pyautogui mousehold function to drag the slider down